# Oracle SQL: Convert number of digits to maximum number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 1 with a column NUMBER_OF_DIGITS and another table 2 with a column READING_VALUE

I want to get the values from table 2 which are nearing maximum value

Example: NUMBER_OF_DIGITS - 4 , maximum value is 9999 and I need to get the values nearest to 9999 from table 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Table 1</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>PK</th>
    <th>NUMBER_OF_DIGITS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Table 2</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>PK</th>
    <th>VALUE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>9990</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>99789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>23456</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Do you mean "nearest" or do you mean "nearest, but without exceeding the number of digits"? Example: number_of_digits = 4, maximum value is 9999, and the values in table 2 are 1000 and 10001. The value 10001 is closest to 9999 - but it is five digits. Is that the desired result, or is 1000 the desired result? (Also, if the values were 10 and 10001, would you choose 10, or do you ONLY need numbers that are four digits?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the join you will have to figure out for yourself:

```
select to_number(substr('99999999999999999', 1, max_digits), '99999999999999999') - Table2.READING_VALUE as Val_Diff
from Table1
inner join Table2
on Somecommoncol = someothercommoncol
```

Comment: You are a savior! Oracle doesn't support LEFT but I was able to rewrite with SUBSTR.